# I am experiencing an "Item qty Declaration Error" in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

**Problem:**
I am experiencing an *"Item qty Declaration Error"* in Magento when a logged-in user adds items to the cart.

**Description:**
Unexpectedly, the *"Item qty Declaration Error"* message is shown with every cart item, but only for logged-in users.

[image: Item qty Declaration Error]

Non-logged-in or guest users do not encounter this error.

[image: No Error in NonLoggedIn User]

**Steps taken:**

1. I investigated the code and found that the error originates from the `checkdata()` function in `vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem.php` when the `setQty()` function is called.
2. I added a print statement to display the exception message, and it revealed the error message *"Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path."*
3. The error seems to be caused by the use of the `setQty()`.

[image: Error Throwing Code]

**Expected Outcome:**
I expected the *"Item qty Declaration Error"* to not occur when logged-in users add items to the cart.

**Additional information:**

- **Magento version:** 2.4.5
- **Theme:** Claue Theme
- **Minimum Quantity:** 0.5 (Allow Decimal Qty:Yes)